# Consuming a Web Service in Delphi 2007

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007

Can any one explain or help me create a code to consume the following Web Service: http://207.150.244.30:9000/txserver/1?wsdl  I've worked with this web service but with no luck!

Answer (score 2):

Simply let the `WSDL Importer` do the stuff for you. Go to `File / New / Other` and there go to `Delphi Projects / WebServices / WSDL Importer`. In the wizard just paste your web service definition link you've posted and finish the wizard. Delphi will generate complete unit including all classes, functions and properties.
.....................................................................................................................................................................

Complex guide for creating web service clients you can find for instance [here](http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/Delphi-Kylix/Creating-a-Web-Service-Client-with-Delphi/).